Adding more than one image as album art to m4a via command line
Adding more than one image as album art to mp3 via command line was already explained at Superuser.
I would like to know how to do this for m4a audio files to have a front and back cover.
I know that the GUI Mp3tag can add and show several images to m4a files.

I think the question is first to you, which command line tool you're using to edit/manage the m4a audio files at all? (The linked question was asking about eyeD3 which doesn't work for m4a files)

Since I don't think there are many options I'm open to any tool that works. Ffmpeg would be nice.

I was able to add two cover arts to an m4a file using AtomicParsley (a command line program for reading, parsing, and setting metadata into MPEG-4 files).
The command to do that is:
AtomicParsley.exe sample.m4a --artwork 1.png --artwork 2.png --overWrite

You can also do the same thing with ffmpeg (it's not my first choice since ffmpeg isn't only for metadata, so it's more likely to mess something up):
ffmpeg.exe -i sample.m4a -i 1.png -i 2.png -map 0 -map 1 -map 2 -c copy -disposition:1 attached_pic -disposition:2 attached_pic output.m4a


Thank you. That's great. And how could I remove one of the images again?

You would need to know which specific stream you want to remove (which is difficult if you can't see the image...) and remove it with something like this (for the 2nd cover) ffmpeg.exe -i "input.m4a" -map 0 -map -0:2 -c copy "output.m4a"

Great! Thank you!

I can't speak to AtomicParsley, but I have my doubts, because ffmpeg still doesn't show you both images.  I got the ffmpeg command to run.  It even attached it.  But like I said, you can attach the second pic to nearly any file format.  It's not going to show it to you.  Result of ffmpeg

@JayCravens Thanks, that's interesting. But just because Thunar doesn't show the second image doesn't mean its not there.

There's no way that will show you both images.  Even if you attach the other one as data, it won't be of much use.  The only way to display both covers is to combine them first.  You'll need ImageMagick to use montage.
#!/bin/bash

montage "$2" "$3" -tile 2x1 -geometry +0+0 covers.jpg

ffmpeg -i "$1" -i covers.jpg -c copy -disposition:v attached_pic out-"$1" && mv out-"$1" "$1"

rm covers.jpg

exit 0

Save as: m4a_artwork.sh
Change mode executable: chmod +x m4a_artwork.sh
Usage: ./m4a_artwork.sh "your_file.m4a" "cover_front.jpg" "cover_back.jpg"

But I know that Mp3tag can add and show more images. I updated my questions accordingly.

@FrankBreitling I guess the follow-up question is, is it a standard that multiple images are recognized for m4a files, or is it Mp3tag's own customization/feature?

@AndrewT Yes, I wonder, too. Please tell us, if someone has the answer.

@FrankBreitling Not that I'm aware of, not for .m4a.  There's a way to include a data attachment, but it's not going to display it.  I think the only reason that mpeg-4 audio gets away with showing you the one image is that it's encoded as a single frame of video. If it can be done, I've not run into it, but never say never! (I don't think currently it's possible though.)
